# Macbook Pro 2007 crashes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, performance, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro 2007 with 4GB of RAM 320GB. I bought this MacBook off eBay over the summer. It came with Leopard, 2 months later then I upgrade to Snow Leopard, then to Mountain Lion. I currently have Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

The screen kind of flickers and I don't know if it's the graphics card or it's just the screen. But one day I was using my computer and all of sudden it just turns gray and the screen starts flickering and it just kept going. I don't think it's the screen because this flickering shuts down my computer and kernel panics come up.

When you restart the computer, the Apple logo that comes up looks like it has spots on it but doesn't boot. It stays and it freezes and restarts my computer. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

It very well may be the graphics card in your MacBook Pro. Apparently during the manufacturing process (of this generation) too much thermal paste was applied to the heatsink on the GPU, thus cooking it. *If* this is the case for you, Apple *might* replace it or reimburse you for repair, if they are still doing this.

A few good links:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4132?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason your laptop is crashing is because of extra thermal paste applied to it. Try to remove the thermal paste with the help of a dry cloth and reapply it again to see if helps in fixing the issue.
You can get more help from this guide: https://pcbuildinglab.com/too-much-thermal-paste/

If nothing changes, then try to reach Apple Customer Support Center, and hopefully they'll replace it

Comment: I could see this possibly being a solution for a PC but the original question is about a Mac and a laptop at that. Please provide additional information as to **how** the solution you suggest could apply to a Mac laptop.